# How to track a particular page in order to address the loading speed issue

Tags: filters

Whenever I try to load a page of a particular website, I get the message while using Chrome browser on the left bottom 'waiting for xxxxyz.com.' How do I track the particular page so that I can remove the same in order to see if the loading speed can be increased.

Comment: You can use your browsers dev tools to get a view of what's loading, when, how, why, etc with full timings and a timeline. When you say "so that I can remove the same", what are you referring to?

Comment: use query monitor plugin.

Comment: @JoelM I have installed Query Monitor plugin. How do I track the Javascript so that I can remove the same.

Comment: it will show you lots of things in your admin bar, I can't really explain fast. It's not built specifically for tracking javascript, it does many other things. it will let you know if the page is slow for other reasons such as slow queries or http requests and a bunch of other stuff you might not know about. It will also show you which javascript files are loaded. if there are too many of them or they are not deferred or w/e then IMO there isn't much worth doing about it. This is what you get when you use lots of plugins or crap plugins in WordPress.

Comment: to see query monitor results just visit pages while logged in as admin. it will either show a thing in your admin bar or at the bottom of your page or both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the diagnosed problem in the words of hosting provider on chat: 'The site just wants to load javascript from affiliates.xxx.com and all of those requests the site makes to affiliates.xxxx.com don't work and take a very long time to actually try and work bringing the site's loading speed down.'

Will changing the theme address this issue?

Comment: @Tomjnowell  I want to remove the Java Scripts that are delaying.

Comment: I understand  defer parsing of Javascript should help and so will be trying a plugin related with this.